# How to get the Directory name and file name of a bash script by bash?

Tags: linux, bash, path, filenames

Follow are known. Possible it helps:

Get the filename.extension incl. fullpath:

Script: `/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/bashfile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $0

read -r
```

Output:

```
/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/bashfile.sh
```

Get filename.extension:

Script: `/path/path/path/path/path/bashfile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ${0##*/}

read -r
```

Output:

```
bashfile.sh
```

## Question:

## How to get directory name and file name of a bash script by bash ?

```
Script: `/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/bashfile.sh`
```

Wanted output:

```
/path5/bashfile.sh
```

Remark:
Perhaps its possible, if you look from right side, remove all left from "/*/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "/$(basename "$(dirname "$0")")/$(basename "$0")"
echo
echo

read -r
```

Output:

```
/Dirname/Filname.Extension
```

Answer (score 1):

```
readlink -f $0 |awk -F"/" '{print "/"$(NF-1)"/"$NF}'
# or
awk -F"/" '{print "/"$(NF-1)"/"$NF}' <(readlink -f $0)
# or 
awk -F"/" '{print "/"$(NF-1)"/"$NF}' <<<$(readlink -f $0)
# or
sed -E 's/^(.*)(\/\w+\/\w+\.\w+$)/\2/g' <(readlink -f $0)
```

output

```
/path5/bashfile.sh
```

Comment: Every of your 4 solutions are giving 3 lines output on LMDE4.

Comment: @linda54 works fine on ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Little bit shorter than the first fitting solution:

Script: `/path1/path2/path3/path4/path5/bashfile.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(($(echo $0 | tr -dc "/" | wc -m)+1))
echo "/""$(echo "$0" | cut -d"/" -f$(($n-1)),$n)"

read -r
```

Output:

```
/path5/bashfile.sh
```

Perhaps they are a shorter solution.